# UPDATE all values of a column with a single value, if that value is present, for all users

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.6

I have table like this:

```
ID | cur_val | done  | res 
1  | 10000   | false | false
2  | 20000   | false | false
3  | 30000   | false | false
1  | 40000   | false | false
3  | 60000   | false | false
1  | 10000   | true  | false
```

I need an update query to update the `res` column (which is `false` by default) depending on the values from the `done` column.
Specifically, for any `ID`, if `done` is `true`, then all the `res` values associated with that `ID` should be updated to `true`.

The final table should look like this:

```
ID | cur_val | done  | res 
1  | 10000   | false | true
2  | 20000   | false | false
3  | 30000   | false | false
1  | 40000   | false | true
3  | 60000   | false | false
1  | 10000   | true  | true
```

I'd appreciate any help with this.

Comment: You shouldn't store such a value, because when users come and go, your data will soon be inconsistent. Create a view instead, will always be up to date!

Comment: @jarlh Could you please explain a bit more? I'm pretty new to SQL.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `sql server`

```
UPDATE t1
SET res = 1
FROM yourtable t1
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT 1
     FROM yourtable t2
     WHERE t1.ID = t2.ID
       AND done = 1)
```

in `postgres`

```
UPDATE yourtable t1
SET res = true
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT 1
     FROM yourtable t2
     WHERE t1.id = t2.id
       AND done = true)
;
```

Comment: Your query sets the all of `res` to true, instead of just setting it for the `id` which has `done` = `true`. Here's a sample execution [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/bf3b5/3). Can you please check? Thanks!

Comment: @Arty I the original code was written for sql server  I added postgresql version of the query as well.

Comment: Thank you! That works, and I've accepted your answer.